# Bitcoinj stuck after chain split

Tags: bitcoinj, chain-reorganization, stale-block

I am using LevelDBFullPrunedBlockStore as a BlockChain. once in every 2-3 chainsplit in the network my bitcoinJ node stops to download new block. The scenario is always the same

1)My node get block on height x that network will mark as orphaned later
2)My node gets block x+1 (from mainchain) and says that block x (orphaned by the network later) will be orphaned 
3)My node get the mainchain block on height x and says that "could not verify block"

Later peers are sending me single transactions, but I am unable to download any more blocks, there is no logs about the new block at all. I did not change anything in the code that is responsible for block persistence. When I restart the application it does not download any new block as well.

Here is log form Saturday where it happend:

```
2017-05-13 22:45:56 INFO  AbstractBlockChain:597 - Block forks the chain at height 466251/block 000000000000000000c0b4c4e062b8cc77a5fd3dc5594bee9fd5a8cacdeba92b, but it did not cause a reorganize:
000000000000000001b3699313793566fb947d554173c5f19fe790e597adedbf
2017-05-13 22:45:56 INFO  AbstractBlockChain:926 - Connected orphan 00000000000000000005b2d8a9d429b050a5a9ba4d44dbe1543280d6e89b77af
2017-05-13 22:45:56 INFO  AbstractBlockChain:576 - Block is causing a re-organize
2017-05-13 22:45:56 INFO  AbstractBlockChain:752 - Re-organize after split at height 466251
2017-05-13 22:45:56 INFO  AbstractBlockChain:753 - Old chain head: 000000000000000000c89a56fec1a04a5981e7f614e6ba2f877559fc2ef9e138
2017-05-13 22:45:56 INFO  AbstractBlockChain:754 - New chain head: 00000000000000000005b2d8a9d429b050a5a9ba4d44dbe1543280d6e89b77af
2017-05-13 22:45:56 INFO  AbstractBlockChain:755 - Split at block: 000000000000000000c0b4c4e062b8cc77a5fd3dc5594bee9fd5a8cacdeba92b
2017-05-13 22:45:57 WARN  Peer:1025 - [2a03:4000:2:496:0:0:0:8]:8333: Block verification failed
org.bitcoinj.core.VerificationException: Could not verify block:
 block: 
   hash: 000000000000000001b3699313793566fb947d554173c5f19fe790e597adedbf
   version: 536870912 (BIP34, BIP66, BIP65)
   previous block: 000000000000000000c0b4c4e062b8cc77a5fd3dc5594bee9fd5a8cacdeba92b
   merkle root: dcf81e3a220fa3a14ed09cd76497e13fb9c9affeef9c9ce052c9c1e1854fac26
   time: 1494708074 (2017-05-13T20:41:14Z)
   difficulty target (nBits): 402781863
   nonce: 2897470832
   with 2100 transaction(s):
  8a0d0a5f11ef31f974f59658c27824b2ddacba88e6b6dfa1865caa48bf4bb444
```

Did anyone had the same issue? I have no clue what I suppose to do.